# Changing global variable when button is clicked using a function

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to update cartSummary every time a button is clicked. (The button is working but cartSummary does not update when called outside of the function)
There are multiple buttons which is why i need to be able to update cartSummary.

```
var price = 0;
var totalPrice = 0;

var cartSummary = "";

function addProduct1() {
    price = product1.price;
    cartSummary = cartSummary + product1.name + " €" + product1.price + "\n";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cartSummary;
}

function addProduct1() {
    price = product1.price;
    cartSummary = cartSummary + product1.name + " €" + product1.price + "\n";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cartSummary;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cartSummary;
```

There are multiple buttons which is why i need to be able to update cartSummary.

Comment: add html whatever you tried.

Comment: just need to append to the cardSummary not just assign var t = "something" or t +="more item"

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `addProduct1` function twice. I assume you meant to use a different name for each function.

Other than that, you are rewriting the value of `cartSummary` every time the `addProduct1` function is called.

Replace the statement

```
cartSummary = cartSummary + product1.name + " €" + product1.price + "\n";
```

with

```
cartSummary += product1.name + " €" + product1.price + "\n";
```

Note the `cartSummary +=` part that appends the string instead of rewriting.

Comment: Hi Thank you, I believe you accidentally kept cartSummary after +=. Getting rid of that worked perfect. Another Question if you don't mind. The new line statement I added at the end "\n" did not work. What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I will update the answer. For the new line, use ```"<br>"``` instead of ```"\n"```.

Comment: Hello sorry for bothering you again but i am having a similar issue calculating the total cost

Comment: var price = 0;
var totalPrice = 0;


var cartSummary = "";

function addProduct1() {
 price = product1.price;
 cartSummary += product1.name + " €" + product1.price + "<br>";
 totalPrice += price;
 document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = cartSummary;  
}

Comment: The total cost stays at 0

Answer (score 0):

outside the button if you want the dom manipulation to work you need to wait for the DOM to be ready. You try following approaches to make it work.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cartSummary; 
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cartSummary; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you I will take this into account for later projects but currently being asked to use this format. Much appreciated none the less.